# Why this Fixture is running its constructor more than once?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

Why the following `xUnit` test doesn't get passed. `ProgramFixture` constructor is running 3 times, but I just want to keep the same instance for all tests, so the `Count` property should be: 1, 2, 3 in a sequence. Why it's giving me: 1, 1, 1 as it's instantiating a new `ProgramFixture` for every `InlineData` test.

Program:

```
namespace UnitTest
{
    public sealed class Program
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public void IncrementCount()
        {
            ++this.Count;
        }

        // Mandatory Main method for the entry point.
        public static void Main() { }
    }
}
```

xUnit:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xunit;

namespace UnitTestTests
{
    public sealed class ProgramFixture : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposed = false;

        public UnitTest.Program Program { get; }

        public ProgramFixture()
        {
            this.Program = new();
            Debug.WriteLine("################## ProgramFixture constructor runned.");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (this.disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("################## ProgramFixture disposed.");
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public sealed class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<ProgramFixture>
    {
        private readonly ProgramFixture programFixture;

        public UnitTest1(ProgramFixture programFixture)
        {
            this.programFixture = programFixture;
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData(1)]
        [InlineData(2)]
        [InlineData(3)]
        public void Test1(int expectedCount)
        {
            this.programFixture.Program.IncrementCount();

            Assert.Equal(expectedCount, this.programFixture.Program.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

When debugging it:
[image]

***I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 16.10.3***

Is that a bug on `Visual Studio` or some machine specific bug?

***EDIT***

My Project files:

Program:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

xUnit:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.9.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.0.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UnitTest\UnitTest.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

***EDIT 2***

I noticed I have inverted the `Assert.Equal` method signature order for its parameters, so I edited `Assert.Equal(this.programFixture.Program.Count, expectedCount)` to `Assert.Equal(expectedCount, this.programFixture.Program.Count)` so in the first Error screenshot the expected and actual values shown at the right panel are different from this one, however the problem still the same.

[image]

Comment: I've just tried this, and I don't see the behavior you're describing - I *do* see counts of 1, 2 and 3, but with the assertions not necessarily in the order that the inline test data is specified.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did update the question with more info, it's weird because in my machine they don't get passed. If you reproduced the same way so it makes me think some kind of bug however my `Visual Studio Community 2019` is up to date.

Comment: Note that you're showing a success for your "3" test - which suggests in that run it's just the first two that are the wrong way round. (It's also slightly confusing because you've got the expected and actual arguments the wrong way round in your test.) But when I debug through the code, it only shows the constructor running once. Perhaps include your project file so we can see your dependency versions?

Comment: @JonSkeet As you requested question has been updated in the EDIT section. Also noticed that sometimes the constructor runs 1 time as you described, but if you run the test more times it will eventually run 2 or even 3 as in the screenshot.

Comment: I've just run it several times, and not seen it happen once. I don't know what's going on on your machine, I'm afraid :(

Comment: @JonSkeet Looks like I'm not the only one having the same issue: github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/120

Comment: That was 7 years ago, and fixed in VS 2013... I think it unlikely to actually be the same cause.

Comment: @JonSkeet Bug confirmed: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug confirmed and bug report has been filled on https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2347. Unfortunately I'm forced to use a less idiomatic unit test approach but at least it's robust, reliable and works without none of the issues mentioned, and fits for the purpose of another object attributes other than `Count` to preserve its same state during this single test context:

Program:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace UnitTest
{
    public sealed class Program : IDisposable
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }

        private bool disposed = false;

        public Program()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("################## Program constructor runned.");
        }

        public void IncrementCount()
        {
            ++this.Count;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (this.disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("################## Program disposed.");
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }

        // Mandatory Main method for the entry point.
        public static void Main() { }
    }
}
```

xUnit:

```
using Xunit;

namespace UnitTestTests
{
    public sealed class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            using (var program = new UnitTest.Program())
            {
                int[] expectedCounts = { 1, 2, 3 };

                foreach (var expectedCount in expectedCounts)
                {
                    program.IncrementCount();
                    Assert.Equal(expectedCount, program.Count);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```